# Beamer template with blue bars at top and bottom

Tags: beamer

How can I obtain something like this in beamer?

[image]

Comment: should there be any text in the blue bars?

Comment: @samcarter yes, there will be text in both of them

Comment: Which text? It would be easier to know what the purpose of the blue bars is to choose the appropriate beamer template to modify.

Comment: @samcarter The the top bar I would like to put the slide title

Comment: At in the bottom one?

Comment: Should the box for the frametitle be on all slides or only on the ones which have a frametitle?

Comment: Even the bottom one would have different text per slide. For the frametitle, it should be present in all the slides except the first and last ones.

Answer (score 2):

Some custom defined headline, frametitle and footline template to add blue lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=blue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue,fg=white}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{frametitle}\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \vskip-1cm%
      \begin{minipage}[c][\headheight][c]{\textwidth}%
        \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
        \strut\insertframetitle\par
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\strut\insertframesubtitle\par}%
      \fi
    }%      
      \vspace*{-0.1cm}
      \end{minipage}%
  \vskip-0.1em
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.5ex,dp=3.125ex]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot} bar
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \framesubtitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty the same of what I need but I would like to change the text in the top bar for every slide.